# Presentation Mode Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an App to stream a video on my secondary display connected via HDMI on my device using Android's Presentation mode.
I ran a simple Layout on Secondary display and I was able to do that.. But when I launch my app It blocks my Activity on Primary screen and I can't do anything except killing the app.

I found this code somewhere on Internet. It is simple code and it throws "R.layout.presentation_with_media_router_content" on my secondary screen properly but I can't do anything on my primary screen at all until I kill this app from adb.

Both of my screen is connected through HDMI (HDMI 1 & HDMI 2). Any help on how to enable my Primary display while running presentation mode on secondary will help. Btw I'm using Android N for this development.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton sendtoback;
    private PresentationActivity presentationActivity;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // init Presentation Class
        DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        Display[] presentationDisplays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
        if (presentationDisplays.length > 0) {
            // If there is more than one suitable presentation display, then we could consider
            // giving the user a choice.  For this example, we simply choose the first display
            // which is the one the system recommends as the preferred presentation display.
            Display display = presentationDisplays[0];
            PresentationActivity presentation = new PresentationActivity(this, display);
            presentation.show();
            this.presentationActivity =  presentation;
        }
      }
    public void changeText (String s) {
        this.presentationActivity.setText(s);
    }

    public void SendOnBack(View view){
        Log.i("VideoApp","StartVideoApp");
    }

}


class PresentationActivity extends Presentation {

    private TextView text;
    private PresentationActivity presentation;

    public PresentationActivity(Context outerContext, Display display) {
        super(outerContext, display);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.presentation_with_media_router_content);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        this.text = text;
        text.setText("test");

    }

    public void setText(String s) {
        this.text.setText(s);

    }
}
```

Thanks, Satish

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to start the `Presentation` on the secondary display. The method is called from `onResume`, and it works flawlessly.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void doDisplay() {

    DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();

    MediaRouter mediaRouter = (MediaRouter) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
    MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);

    if (displays.length > 1) {
        Display presentationDisplay = route.getPresentationDisplay();
        if (presentationDisplay != null) {
            presentation = new MyPresentation(MainActivity.this, presentationDisplay);
            presentation.setAppListener(this);
            presentation.show();
        }
     }
}
```

Did you try on a version of Android other than N? I have run my code on 4.4 and 6.0